# Finding out if User has logged out of Gmail/Google (with or without Google API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I currently sign in a user on my website through the Google API (on ruby, using https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). I would like to know if there is a way for my application to find out if the user has signed out of their Google Account.

Is there anything in the Google API that would handle this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you searched? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried out a few APIs on the OAuth2 Playground, specifically the Gmail API. But I believe the token that I receive back from can't necessarily be used to find out whether the user is still logged in. My guess was that I could try to hit the Gmail API and get the feed. If the token isn't able to get the feed then the Account isn't logged in anymore. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Do a GET on "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox" and if the response body has:

```
<input id="Passwd"
```

in it then they're not logged in.  However, this might be fragile if Google someday changes their fields.  I tried to see if the response code would be a 30x but it's 200 for both logged in and non-logged in users.